# Unable to curl my EC2 instance to get my EC2 instance information

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to follow these [Instance Metadata and User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) documentation.

I am trying to curl my EC2 instance but for some reason it give me connection refused. I have allowed incoming requests for `HTTP` and `SSH`, and allowed all traffic for outgoing traffic in my security group. I am able to `ssh` in its but unable to `curl`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have execute `curl` from "inside" the instance, not from outside.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I am executing 
curl http://<PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS>/latest/meta-data/
after ssh and I'm getting
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS> port 80: Connection refused

Comment: You have to connect to metadata server: `169.254.169.254` not public IP address.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! Its working :)

Answer (score 8):

The [Amazon EC2 instance metadata service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) is available from within the Amazon EC2 instance itself, via this URL:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

Comment: The previous downvote on this question is quite ridiculous.  This is obviously correct.

Comment: How about, if you are connecting locally and thru a docker instance only?

Answer (score 2):

Posting this to avoid other people finding this via google search getting confused.

@John Rotenstein's Answer was 100% correct back in the past,
(it's accurate for V1 of the metadata service.)

In 2024 EC2 instances now use V2 of the metadata service.
So the above command will fail if tried today.

```bash
# If you add the -v --verbose flag
# Or the -i --include flag
curl -v  http://169.254.169.254/latest/
curl -i  http://169.254.169.254/latest/
# You'll see HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

The following works with the newer v2 of the metadata URL

```bash
export TOKEN=$(curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600")

echo $TOKEN

curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -i http://169.254.169.254/latest/
# ^-- now says HTTP/1.1 200 OK

# A nice shorthand hack to make v2 feel like v1
# (that's probably best done in the active shell only)
# and not in a .bashrc or .zshrc file
alias curl='curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN"'
curl -i http://169.254.169.254/latest/
# ^-- now says HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```